# How to construct akka TestFSMRef with parameters?

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I am trying to test an Akka FSM using the [information provided here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/testing.html#testfsmref). However I cannot figure out how to create a `TestFSMRef` when my subclass of `Actor with FSM` requires parameters for instantiation.

For standard, non-FSM tests, I create the `TestActorRef` via:

```
val testActor = TestActorRef(MyActorFSM.props("nl", p1, p2))
```

where the `.props` method is implemented as per the [documented Recommended Practice](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html). I have tried instantiating a `testActor` and then passing that to the TestFSMRef constructor:

```
val fsm = TestFSMRef(testActor)
```

but that does not compile:

```
inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,akka.testkit.TestActorRef[Nothing]]
do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [S,D,T <: akka.actor.Actor]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing the code from akka's example FSM actor, I tweaked it a bit to have two constructor params and it now looks like this:

```
class MyFSMActor(foo:String, bar:Int) extends Actor with FSM[State,Data]{
  println(s"My foo = $foo and my bar = $bar")
  startWith(Idle, Uninitialized)

  when(Idle) {
    case Event(SetTarget(ref), Uninitialized) =>
      stay using Todo(ref, Vector.empty)
  }

  // transition elided ...

  when(Active, stateTimeout = 1 second) {
    case Event(Flush | StateTimeout, t: Todo) =>
      goto(Idle) using t.copy(queue = Vector.empty)
  }

  // unhandled elided ...

  initialize()
}
```

Then, I can create a test ref to it like so:

```
val test = TestFSMRef(new MyFSMActor("hello", 1))
println(test.stateName)
```

When I do that, I see:

```
My foo = hello and my bar = 1
Idle
```

You normally don't invoke the `Actor`s constructor directly (and it will fail if you do), but wrapping it in a `TestActorRef` or a `TestFSMRef` will allow you to get around that limitation.  I hope this helps you get your code working.